# Breakpoints conditionated by default

Tags: php, eclipse, debugging

**Context**

Eclipse for PHP Developers
Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)
Build id: 20180405-1200

**The problem**

Every breakpoints I create, are created with "Enable Set Condition" checked, and an empty condition. To use them as non-conditional breakpoints (95% of times) I have to open breakpoint properties panel and uncheck this checkbox.

**Reproduction**

1. Double click on left side ruler:

   [image]
2. Breakpoint automatically configured as conditionated:

[image]

I don't know if it's a bug, and/or if it can be re-configured... Any ideas?

Comment: Why you want disable this? If condition is empty it's always true.

Comment: My god! Sorry: You are in reason: maybe yesterday my tests were wrong. False alarm :/ SOLVED